# Scrapy ---- Error ImportError: No module named tutorial.settings

Tags: python, scrapy

Scrapy document says

> Scrapy will look for configuration parameters in ini-style scrapy.cfg files in standard locations: /etc/scrapy.cfg

I have put the `scrapy.cfg` in the location `/etc/scrapy.cfg` and tried to run
`scrapy crawl <spider_name>` in the project root directory `tutorial`.
I am getting error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/user/.local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())

  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 110, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()

  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 68, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')

File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 292, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)

ImportError: No module named tutorial.settings
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create your project with `scrapy startproject project_name`? If so, the files should be all placed in their right places. Also, AFAIK `scrapy.cfg` should be in your project's root folder, not in `/etc`.

Comment: I created project with scrapy startproject project_name and the project structure is tutorial/
    scrapy.cfg           
    tutorial/             
        __init__.py
        items.py          
        middlewares.py    
        pipelines.py      
        settings.py     
        spiders/         
            __init__.py
   I just moved the scrapy.cfg to /etc/ to check if the scrapy picks the file from the said standard location.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow this tutorial https://towardsdatascience.com/a-minimalist-end-to-end-scrapy-tutorial-part-ii-b917509b73f7

and I ran to the same problem, in my case I had this issue cuz the file scrapy.cfg was inside the folder tutorial, I move the file to the root of the project and it solved the problem, so the correct format will be

```
scrapy-tutorial-start
---tutorial
   ----settings.py
   ----spider
       ---yourspyders
---venv
---other files
---scrapy.cfg
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `tutorial/settings.py`. Your output contains this complain: `ImportError: No module named tutorial.settings`, so, may be it need this file to run.

Comment: I created project with scrapy startproject project_name and the project structure is

Comment: I created project with scrapy startproject project_name and the project structure is tutorial/
    scrapy.cfg           
    tutorial/             
        __init__.py
        items.py          
        middlewares.py    
        pipelines.py      
        settings.py     
        spiders/         
            __init__.py
   I just moved the scrapy.cfg to /etc/ to check if the scrapy picks the file from the said standard location.